# Migrate mailbox to O365 with onprem database not mounted

Tags: office365, exchange-server

We have problems with a mailbox databases on prem exchange 2013 server, it shows as Dismounted. We have try everything to repair and mount the database again but not luck.
We were just in the process of migrate all the mailboxes to O365, but a few mailbox are stored in the affected database.
Is there anyway to migrate these few mailboxes to O365 without having the databases mounted, we are assuming lossing the content of the mailbox but at least give the mailbox email service again.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the answer to my question, but this is what I did to fix the issue.

Recover the databases following the steps describe with the next link:
https://howardsimpson.blogspot.com/2018/04/failed-to-mount-database-error-an-active-manager-operation-failed-operation-failed-with-message-MapiExceptionDatabaseError.html

Basically this command:

eseutil /p "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\Mailbox\Mailbox Database 0969320567\Mailbox Database 0969320567.edb"

Once it is finished, heads up! it take lot of timedepending size of your databases and server resource (for 380 GB took 32 hours), Remove all the old logs or move to another folder (quick sugestion is to rename the current log folder and create an empty one with the same name).

With the new log folder create and the databases in Clean Shutdown, execute the following command:

Mount-Database –Identity “database-name”

Links reference:

https://howardsimpson.blogspot.com/2018/04/failed-to-mount-database-error-an-active-manager-operation-failed-operation-failed-with-message-MapiExceptionDatabaseError.html

https://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/how-to-use-exchange-extensible-storage-engine-utilities-eseutil-tool/

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53555.exchange-how-to-force-mount-exchange-database.aspx